# How to create a generic Property Accessor without using Reflection?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, properties

How to create a generic Property Accessor without using Reflection?

I'd like to create a generic property accessor class to be able to pass a property object to it then accessing that property value; getting and setting.

I don't like to use Reflection just with Func and Action and lambda expressions.

The problem with the below code is that it makes a copy of the property value and passes it over so it doesn't send the property reference actually whereas I'd like to be able to get and set the Number property of the Product object using the GenericPropertyAccessor class.

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var product = new Product {Number = 1};

        var productNumberAccesstor = new GenericPropertyAccessor<int>(product.Number);

        productNumberAccesstor.Value = 23;

        Console.WriteLine(productNumberAccesstor.Value);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Product
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class GenericPropertyAccessor<T>
{
    private T _property;

    public GenericPropertyAccessor(T propertyExpression)
    {
        _property = propertyExpression;
    }

    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            return Get(() => _property);
        }
        set
        {
            Set(valueInput => _property = valueInput , value);
        }
    }

    static T Get(Func<T> getFunc)
    {
        return getFunc();
    }

    static void Set(Action<T> setAction, T value)
    {
        setAction(value);
    }

}
```

Basically, what should I pass to the constructor of GenericPropertyAccessor to enable this?

I know one solution would be as below but is it possible to even simplify this further? Specially on the constructor of the GenericPropertyAccessor. Is it possible to move the lambda expressions to the class and only passing a kind of property reference.

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var product = new Product {Number = 1};

            var productNumberAccesstor = new GenericPropertyAccessor<int>(() => product.Number, value => product.Number = value);

            productNumberAccesstor.Value = 23;

            Console.WriteLine(productNumberAccesstor.Value);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class Product
    {
        public int Number { get; set; }
    }

    public class GenericPropertyAccessor<T>
    {
        private readonly Func<T> _getFunc;
        private readonly Action<T> _setAction;

        public GenericPropertyAccessor(Func<T> getFunc, Action<T> setAction)
        {
            _getFunc = getFunc;
            _setAction = setAction;
        }

        public T Value
        {
            get
            {
                return _getFunc();
            }
            set
            {
                _setAction(value);
            }
        }
    }
```

I mean how to pass the "product.Number" expression inside the class?

Comment: .NET has no non-reflection way to reference a property. The same goes for events. The existing answers are as good as it gets.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to pass in the delegates you are currently creating internally:

```
public class GenericPropertyAccessor<T>
{
    private Func<T> _getter;
    private Action<T> _setter;

    public GenericPropertyAccessor(Func<T> getter, Action<T> setter)
    {
        _getter = getter;
        _setter = setter;
    }

    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            return _getter();
        }
        set
        {
            _setter(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
new GenericPropertyAccessor<int>(() => product.Number, v => product.Number = v);
```

Comment: But that makes it not easy to use.

Comment: how would you move the delegates inside the class and just pass the property reference? I mean how to pass the "product.Number" expression inside the class?

Comment: @TheLight You would need to use Expressions for this. This is a good option, if the ratio between creating `GenericPropertyAccessor` instances and using them is low, i.e. few instances that are used very often. But if the ratio is different, it isn't such a good option, because creating the expression trees for the getters and setters and compiling them has its own runtime costs.

Answer (score 2):

Below are two ways of achieving this: one with LINQ `Expression`s and the other with plain Lambda functions.  Expressions are simpler to invoke than Lambdas, but both can be simplified a little further from a usage perspective.

We can create a factory class that simplifies the invocation somewhat:

```
// the Factory method:
public static class Factory
{
    // Wrapper for Expression-based accessor:
    public static Accessor<T> Accessor<T>(Expression<Func<T>> e)
    {
        return new Accessor<T>(e);
    }

    // Wrapper for Lambda-based accessor:
    public static Accessor<T> Accessor<T>(Func<T> _get, Action<T> _set)
    {
        return new Accessor<T>(_get, _set)
    }
}
```

**With Expressions**

If your restriction on using reflection doesn't extend to LINQ Expressions you could simplify the invocation a little further by passing in just a `() => object.Property` style getter expression and generate the setter from it like this:

```
public class Accessor<TProp> : IAccessor<TProp>
{
    private readonly Func<TProp> _getter;
    private readonly Action<TProp> _setter;

    internal Accessor(Expression<Func<TProp>> e)
    {
        if (!(e.Body is System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression))
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid expression type supplied.", "e");
        MemberExpression memacc = (MemberExpression)e.Body;
        if (memacc.Type != typeof(TProp))
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid expression return type.", "e");

        var parmValue = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TProp), "value");
        var assign = Expression.Assign(memacc, parmValue);

        _getter = e.Compile();
        _setter = Expression.Lambda<Action<TProp>>(assign, new[] { parmValue }).Compile();
    }

    public TProperty Value
    {
        get { return _getter(_instance); }
        set { _setter(_instance, value); }
    }
}

// usage:
var obj = new TextBox();
var acc = Factory.Accessor(() => obj.Enabled);
```

The `Expression` compiler support makes this possible.  Instead of compiling the lambda all the way to code it is compiled to an expression tree and that is passed.  The form of this expression allows us to easily create the get and set methods we need very simply.

**Without Expressions**

Without using Expressions you're pretty much restricted to manually providing the get and set methods.  Add (or replace) the following constructor to the Accessor class:

```
    internal Accessor(Func<TProp> getter, Action<TProp> setter)
    {
        _getter = getter;
        _setter = setter;
    }
```

**Usage**

To generate Accessors just call the appropriate factory function:

```
// Object to work on
var obj = new TextBox();

// accessor using Expressions
var acc1 = Factory.Accessor(() => obj.Enabled);

// accessor using Lambdas
var acc2 = Factory.Accessor() => obj.Enabled, v => obj.Enabled = v);
```

Personally I prefer the Expression-based version.